# Use jquery ajax delete function but not running

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-delete

This is my code for delete li element using ajax function but it will not give any output.

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
  type: 'DELETE', 
  url: 'http://example.com', /* url */
  dataType: 'xml', 
  complete: function(response, statusText){ 
       if (statusText == 'success') { 
           jQuery('li.product input[value="B0070X7W9M"]').parent().remove(); 
           /* need to delete li element */
           }
     }
});
```

please help me I am new in jquery ajax.